Looking for resources for following topics for first year student in college
My linear algebra has these topics which i was not able to find in elementary book on Linear algebra. Can someone help ? It should be for first course in Linear algebra. Thanks
" Quadratic Forms, quadratic form as a product
of matrices. The set of quadratic forms over a field.
Congruence of quadratic forms and matrices. Congruent transformations of matrices. Elementary
congruent transformations. Congruent reduction of a symmetric matrix. Matrix Congruence of
skew–symmetric matrices. Reduction in the real field. Classification of real quadratic forms in n
variables. Definite, semi–definite and indefinite real quadratic forms. Characteristic properties of
definite, semi–definite and indefinite forms"

Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Peter Lax contains information on quadratic forms. But I'm surprised that your course requires you to find a textbook on your own. Are you certain there's not a textbook in your syllabus covering the content you listed?
I also found it helpful to check out online resources as needed while working the problem sets. Wikipedia or Stack Exchange I used often.
